# What's stopping me from using arbitrary tags in HTML?

Tags: html, xml, standards, specifications

Even the new HTML5 tags aren't enough to describe structures without falling back to `div`s. What's stopping me from changing:

```
<div class="post">
    <div class="userinfo">
        <span class="name">Casey</span>
        <img class="avatar" src="..." />
    </div>
    <div class="body">
        <p>blah blah blah</p>
        <p>blah blah blah</p>
        <p>blah blah blah</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

into something like:

```
<post>
    <userinfo>
        <name>Casey</name>
        <img class="avatar" src="..." />
    </userinfo>
    <pbody>
        <p>blah blah blah</p>
        <p>blah blah blah</p>
        <p>blah blah blah</p>
    </pbody>
</post>
```

To me, the second example is a lot cleaner. Is there anything (i.e., browser support) stopping me from doing this?

(I realize what it is is, essentially, XML, but in that case, the question becomes, "what does browser support look like for rendering XML web pages?")

Comment: What's stopping you? The specs, duh.

Comment: If you want valid pages that work in all browsers and get crawled by Search Engines - I would really stay away from it. BUT, nothing is stopping you from using XSLT to transform an XML document into HTML. Umbraco uses this **very** successfully.

Comment: Ask **`Jon Skeet`** to create a new language for you.

Comment: @shamittomar i don't get what you are trying to say

Comment: The browser will not know how to style the new tags, you will need to tell it whether to use display: block, inline, etc. Aside from that I am not aware of any reason a browser would not accept the semantic tags you've provided. If we are to make content indexing/searching any smarter we will need meaningful semantic tags like the ones you've included. I can find no reference where the HTML5 spec expressly forbids extensibility (XML). I'd say try it, test it, and if all goes well do it. Otherwise start a petition to get XHTML5 (HTML5+XML) back on track. ( content-type: application/html5+xml )

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Custom/arbitrary HTML tags are supported in all modern browsers. Is there any reason not to use them?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11101389/custom-arbitrary-html-tags-are-supported-in-all-modern-browsers-is-there-any-re)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One reason is that Internet Explorer (and earlier versions of Firefox) don't have a fallback for tags that are not defined and wind up ignoring them for both styling and nesting. [Without a shiv](http://html5doctor.com/how-to-get-html5-working-in-ie-and-firefox-2/), your site will break horribly in those browsers.

Comment: Can't that shortcoming be overcome by adding styling rules such as "display" for the new/arbitrary tags? Undefined style is not a sufficient reason to reject the idea of using valid xml tags as a semantic extension to html5. It is sorely needed if we are to structure documents into meaningful and searchable formats. The W3C added a number of semantic tags, but there is no way they can predict all of the tags that will be needed. HTML5 uses XML syntax, and should support XML extensiblity - with the caveat that the designer MUST tell the browser how to style it. HTML is about markup, not style.

Answer (score 5):

You can use your own tags, but the problem is that since they're not standard, browsers won't know that they may have matching closing tags. And of course, the document won't validate as proper HTML/X-HTML.

```
<blah>
    This is some <span>test</span> test text with another <bogus>tag</bogus> tag
    within, which ends with a fake self-closing <tag />
</blah>
```

Browsers will see `<blah>`, not now how to deal with it, and treat it as essentially "nothing" and ignore it. Then they'll happily parse away on to the next bit, and see some plain text, with a valid span inside. Eventually they'll reach the `</blah>` and ignore that as well.

This is why Javascript and CSS had to support the opening HTML comment sequence as part of their respective language definitions:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--  // <--actually a part of the javascript spec, treated as a comment.
     alert('hey!');
//-->
</script>
```

When Javascript was first introduced, there were still MANY other browsers out there that were entirely unaware of Javascript, and so they'd ignore  tags, and happily output your Javascript code. Ditto for CSS.

If you really need custom tags, you can produce the document as XML with your own DTD attached, and use XSLT to transform it into a valid HTML/X-HTML document.

Comment: regarding the part `browsers won't know that they may have matching closing tags.` i actually think otherwise.. do you have any tests to confirm it?

Comment: `<html><body><blah>You'll see this text</blah></body></html>` Try that in any browser. If unknown tags were ignored and checked for closing tags, you wouldn't see the text.

Comment: @Marc B . I see the text in the latest versions of Chrome / FF / IE / Opera / Safari. I believe it works in any browser you can think which has a share greater than 0.1%  total internet users

Comment: Yes, this is the whole point of my answer. Browsers treat unknown tags as singletons (like a `<br />`) and simply output the tag's inner contents, which is why there's extra hoops to jump through to hide that content from older unaware browsers.

Comment: Pretty much. I'd say any browser which is NOT css/javascript aware is so stone-age that there's literally no point in jumping through hoops to accomodate them. There's graceful degradation and progressive enhancement, but at some point you have to draw the line and tell people they MUST upgrade.

Comment: *"browsers treat unknown tags as singletons"*. that's just plain wrong. browsers treat unknown tags as "container" tags, not singletons. Open up the web inspector and see the document tree for the page `<html><body><blah>You'll see this text</blah></body></html>`. If you are not convinced, try this: `<html><body><blah style="color:red;">You'll see this text</blah></body></html>`

Answer (score 3):

### Good news

- **Nothing is stopping you**
  Use as many custom tags as you like, browsers will know what you mean. Not just the modern ones but IE7+ too.
- **No default look**
  Browsers will treat your tag as unknown and apply no default style to it. No weird margins, paddings, no surprises across clients and platforms. The `display` property is not implied either so give it a value, but after that, everything is as usual. DOM contains your node, `querySelector` works, styles apply, etc.
- **Super readable**
  You'll love the new look of your HTML source.

### Things to consider

1. **Self-closing or not** - to make your tag self-closing, use the good old `<something/>` format, as you would with `<br/>` for example. It's important, otherwise browsers go look for the closing tag. I mean, how could they not.
2. **Future collisions** - that's the only good point from custom tag skeptics: just as we have a lot of new tags in HTML5, it's a possibility that you name a tag "icon" and it will mean something in the next HTML standard, even with a bunch of rendering defaults, and *that can mess your page up badly*. So I'd say, if you want to be on the safe side, use `<dashed-names>` for your tags, they will never ever mess with dashed tag names thanks to the naming of [Web Components](https://coherent-labs.com/posts/web-components/). Also check out [§ 4.13 in HTML standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/custom-elements.html) itself.
3. **Blame magnet effect** - seriously, that's an issue with custom tags, I've been down this road. Use custom tags *only* if everyone working on the same project is on board with it. Otherwise, whenever something breaks it will be your fault "because of your stupid custom tags", and you'll have to change every instance to the usual `<div class="gurgleburgle">`, only to find later that the real issue was totally unrelated.

**TLDR**:

```html
    <custom-tags> Yes you can use them </custom-tags>
```

Answer (score 1):

Most browsers will just treat the tags as arbitrary (like how old browsers treat HTML5 tags). Nothing is stopping you from using your own tags, but it's not a well-accepted way to code HTML. HTML is supposed to use pre-defined tags.

If you're interested in coding with arbitrary tags, you could just go with XML. You can format XML with XSLT (used in a way similar to stylesheets, but much more powerful). Have a look here: http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_xsl.asp

Answer (score 1):

What is the goal of the tags you chose?  If your goal is to present information, then using divs and other presentation-oriented structures is great.  Your tags look more like they are attempting to describe the actual data.  If that is the case, then XML with XSLT transforms on the server side to output HTML for presentation markup is best.  Remember that a browser is simply a rendering engine and it uses the HTML spec as it's blueprint of what to render for a given site.  The browser doesn't need to understand the information like a "post" or "userInfo" because it has no context for undertsanding what to do from a rendering perspective with that information.  CSS can help a browser understand what you want to do visually but ask yourself first whats the goal of having your markup that way, to store your data (XML-style) or to present it.  If to present it, then you should go with the standards if you want to continue to use a browser as your rendering engine.  Good luck, would be great if we could all define our presentation schemes though, fun idea!

Answer (score 1):

getElementsByTagName fails me with custom tags. Example,

```
<acme:mytag id="mytag">
    <div id ="x">x</div>
    <div id ="y">y</div>
    <div id ="z">z</div>
</acme:mytag>
```

This fails with IE8 (Quirks Mode or Standard Mode)

```
var mytag = document.getElementById('mytag'); // it's found
var mydivs = mytag.getElementsByTagName ('div'); // but this is always 0
```

Unless your html tag reads

```
<html XMLNS:acme>
...
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that it would not validate and the new tags would simply be ignored.

Comment: I'm under the impression that validation doesn't mean anything practically, and for the new-tags-ignored issue, CSS can easily fix that (`post, userinfo, pbody { display: block }`).

Comment: @Casey, your impression is incorrect. `display: block` [will not fix the missing tags issue in IE](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/how-to-make-all-browsers-render-html5-mark-up-correctly-even-ie6/): no styles will be applied to elements IE doesn't understand. You need to use another solution (JavaScript or HTC) to get IE to understand the tags. It also doesn't fix issues with earlier versions of Firefox, which will re-nest unknown elements.

Comment: It should be mentioned in this answer that it only applies to IE and other older browsers.

Comment: It should be mentioned that this comment is 9 years old and may not have aged well.