# What are the implications of using custom tags in HTML, or What are the advantages of not using custom tags?

Tags: javascript, web-services, web-applications

I am only talking about custom tags which has a start tag and an end tag.

For example:

```
<toy>Content</toy>
```

(And if I really need to support old browsers, I will have the [shiv](http://html5doctor.com/how-to-get-html5-working-in-ie-and-firefox-2/) in)

I want to know what's the advantage of not using custom tags? or what are the implications of using them?

Don't tell me it's bad because it does not follow standards. Tell me what will i lose from not following this standard. Similarly, don't tell me it's good because it follows standards. Tell me what can i gain from following this standard.

Following standards is just a means to an end, and the end is to work in all browsers. So far, all browsers are rendering it in the same way, in the same behavior, even though there are no specifications standardizing this standard. Therefore, an argument like "if we follow standards it will work in more/all browsers" doesn't work simply because it is now already working in all browsers.

To be sure, an argument like "we may have to edit it in the future" is not convincing at all because all evidences show otherwise. (look at what happened to the advocates of draconian)

===

Related threads (but does not answer this question): [What's stopping me from using arbitrary tags in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3593726/whats-stopping-me-from-using-arbitrary-tags-in-html)

Comment: Should work in any browser except old IE version. The only problem I can see is if the tagname you use will be added to the html-spec later, and browsers start treating the tag differently. But I don't really see any reason why you would want to use custom element. Just use a div and add a classname.

Comment: @Gerben on my side, i don't really see any reason why you want to use a div and add a classname when you can simply use custom tags. which is simpler? you be judge

Comment: @Pace: one is standard, the other is not. To me, adhering to the standards is simplest, as I don't have to worry about how a standards-conforming browser or other tool will interpret the HTML.

Comment: @John Saunders . you do in fact mean that one is HTML5-compliant. the second solution is a "standard" by itself. its behavior is consistent throughout the latest browsers. its what i call the "living standard"

Comment: @Pacerier - can you be a bit clearer about why you want to use custom tags? Assuming it works, what benefit do you get? I can understand wanting custom attributes, but not custom tags. Is it just that you think `<div(or span) class="toy">` looks messy compared to `<toy>`? Assuming `<toy>` works in a general sense, how well does it work with screen-readers and other accessibility assistance tools?

Comment: @nnnnnn you totally don't get my point. let me repeat: if there is a semantic tag I say we use the semantic tag. this question is targeted at instead of doing `<div class="asd">` I'm saying we simply do `<asd>` since `<div class="asd">` is just as un-semantical as `<asd>` anyway.

Comment: @nnnnnn `[quote]Assuming it works..[/unquote]` I do not assume things. I've tested it and it works. Besides, i'm curious at how well you'd think a screen-reader and other accessibility assistance tool can interpret `<div class="toy">` any better than it can interpret `<toy>`.

Comment: I know I didn't get your point: that's why I asked you to clarify it. *My* point was that I don't know how accessibility tools will interpret `<toy>`. Will they ignore the tag but still pay attention to the content? Will they ignore the tag *and* the content? Regarding your second comment, you *do* assume things: your original post, though not using the phrase "I assume", indicated your belief that non-standard tags will continue to work well in the future - that is an assumption that is probably correct, but certainly not guaranteed true for all browsers.

Comment: @nnnnnn . you are a funny individual. when you say *Assuming it works..* I simply replied saying: i do not assume that it works. I've tested those non-standard tags (with the latest versions of iPhone/FF/IE/Opera/Chrome) and i'm saying it works. Yet you somehow chose to tie "I do not assume things" with my speculations into the future

Comment: See my question and the relevant answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3593726/whats-stopping-me-from-using-arbitrary-tags-in-html

Comment: @Casey the answers are related to this topic but not relevant at all

Answer (score 2):

You're basically talking about XMLish behavior. Most browsers support this feature, this is why you can use HTML5 tags with the proper styling. Usually browsers treat unknown tags as inline elements and you should style it to fix your needs.

I think the reason that you shouldn't pepper your page with your own custom markup is context. A tag like `<header>` has a distinct meaning that is well understood by software (crawlers, readers). But a tag like `<toy>` has no context attached to it. It only makes meaning to you.

A web page isn't supposed to be a standalone element. It's part of a bigger whole. While a tag such as `<toy>` may make perfect sense to you, it won't mean anything to a bot or other software. This means that machines won't be able to understand your page as well as other pages that use better markup. This is a bad thing since this would effect how your page is ranked or indexed or consumed.

Comment: You can assume if there's a semantic alternative I'd use the semantic alternative. I'm talking about cases when we choose to use <div class="toy"> instead of <toy>.

Comment: but that's the point. div.toy is more semantic as long as you don't have a case of the divititis. Divs have meaning whereas Toy does not

Comment: isn't the whole point of semantic tags in HTML5 because of the reason that div has no meaning?

Comment: That's just because people don't use it properly. `<div class='header'>` is pointless since you already have a header tag that is used. DIVs turned out to be the jack of all trades container

Comment: i've already stated that if there's a semantic alternative (like header which you've pointed out) I'd use the semantic alternative. this question is specifically targeted at cases when there are no semantic alternatives..

Comment: @JohnP just curious. what's the `case of the divitities`?

Comment: @Pacerier that was an example of it :) People using DIVs for just about everything which means that you aren't structuring your content properly. A good structure goes hand in had with semantics.

Comment: I still do not understand what do you mean when you say "divs have meaning whereas Toy does not". Exactly what *meaning* does `<div>` has that `<toy>` does not?

Comment: What I meant was that `<div>` is a division and that has meaning that is not tied to the nature of the document. Bots understand this. On the other hand, `<toy>` only has meaning in the context of your document. Search engines don't have any context here. What if a  chinese person decides to call his tag something else? The context is not general and not defined globally. That's basically XML.

Comment: I mean  yes we all know that `<div>` has the meaning *division* and Bots understand that it is a *division*. my question is that since *division* is never meaningful at all to Bots, thus `<div>` has no *meaning* whatsoever to Bots (they aren't gonna do anything to it but just ignore it), so what *meaning* does `<div>` has that `<toy>` does not?

Comment: DIV was just an example. What about P? STRONG? LI? For example how would you show a list of toys? Use LI or a TOYS wrapper and TOY containers inside? Yes, in this case the DIV is just taken as a container, but the meaning of it is clear to bots. It knows it's used as a container. When you put TOY in there, how does it know what it signifies? Is it a container? is it maybe additional markup for some script (like FBML)? Do you see what I mean?