# Using custom tags to incase proper tags in HTML

Tags: html, tags

After reading [What are the implications of using custom tags in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6245026/what-are-the-implications-of-using-custom-tags-in-html-or-what-are-the-advantag) I have decided to not use custom tags the way I was planning to use them so that I follow standards, and bots may read my code properly.  Although, I wanted to know if rather than using custom tags for *divs*, if incasing these *divs* within custom tags would still cause any negative effect to my source.

I wouldn't be using: `<SomeDiv>` rather than `<div class="SomeDiv">`

Something more along the lines of:

```
<header>
  <nav>
    <div class="navWrap">
      <div class="navGutz">
        NAVBAR
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <logo>
    <div class="logo">
      LOGO
    </div>
  </logo>
</header>

<content>
  <left>
    <div class="myContent">
      <topContent>
        Main content and more divs
      </topContent>
    </div>
  </left>
  <right>
    <div class="sidebar">
      <news>
        News
      </news>
    </div>
  </right>
</content>

<footer>
  <div class="social">
    Social Links
  </div>
  <div class="copyright">
    Copyright
  </div>
</footer>
```

I ask because rather than using comments to label sections, I wanted to use tags.  That way if for any reason I wanted to add style to the section in a whole, I would be able.  Visually looking at it it seems a little redundant, but there would be more to it rather than what is just in the example.

So to restate the question, would incasing my content (that is up to standards) with custom tags cause any sort of negative effects against my site?  Whether it be indexing, crawling, score, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check this article on [DEV](https://dev.to/jfbrennan/custom-html-tags-4788). The article is about Custom HTML tags, Web Components, the Custom Elements spec and the few js libs.

Comment: Good to know! =] Glad I could help!