# Custom/arbitrary HTML tags are supported in all modern browsers. Is there any reason not to use them?

Tags: html

I've noticed that IE9, Firefox and Chrome all allow you to use arbitrary html tags and style those tags with CSS.

Here's a sample HTML file I whipped up to test this, and it *works* across all modern browsers:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <style>
            h3 { font-family: Arial; }
            animals { padding: 20px; display: block; background-color: #eee; }
            dog { background-color: brown; color: white; display: block; padding: 10px; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <animals>
            <dog>
                <h3>Dog</h3>
            </dog>
            <cat>
                <h3>Cat</h3>
            </cat>
            <giraffe>
                <h3>Giraffe</h3>
            </giraffe>
        </animals>
    </body>
</html>
```

Backwards-compatibility aside, if custom tags are supported by modern browsers, why shouldn't I use them (in conjunction with the existing official tag specifications) to make my markup more semantically relevant to the content, the application elements and so forth?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Custom tags... why not?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8906448/custom-tags-why-not)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML5: Why not use my own arbitrary tag names?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16867332/html5-why-not-use-my-own-arbitrary-tag-names)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you stick to the established HTML5 tags, your page will work better with other tools besides browsers, notably, screen readers.  The only program that will understand your new semantics is yours, and you can write yours to understand `<ul class='animals'>` just as well.

When people argue for "better semantics" in HTML, they mean, "choose the tag that best represents the meaning", usually, not a table. They don't mean, "invent a tag that no one but you will understand."

Answer (score 0):

I still get bug reports that some site breaks on *IE6*. While IE9 is a step in the right direction, IE users traditionally have an enormous momentum and old versions are used decades after they should have been buried.

Another issue you might have to keep in mind is *forward* compatibility. A future standard might introduce unwanted behavior for tags you've used in a generic way.

Then there is the undying desire some people have for all code to pass all sorts of validations, which of course won't be possible unless you actually use XHTML and take care to have your markup actually validate as XML...